# Routing issue in Asp.net MVC (404 Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello People i have a list of Customers (with Name and Id) that i have hardcoded in my **Customers** Controller as: [Click to view Customer Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULN0O.png) i am sending list to a view named **Customer** to display all the three customers with their names as links using following code :

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.Customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer";
}

@foreach (var customer in Model)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new { id = customer.Id }, null)
    </li>
}
```

It displays list of customers but problem is when i click any customer name(Which is a link) it gives a HTTP 404 error as :[Click to see Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJKUa.png) 
i have made a **Details** method in Costumers Controller as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

that recieves id of the customer name being clicked and simply displays its name again but it doesnt works and gives 404 error i have debugged the code and what i have found that control never reached the details Method in Controller, is the issue in ActionLink or what ?
Help is highly appreciated thank you

Comment: You cannot navigate to a POST method. Remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from the `Details()` method

Comment: yes i have understood it sir thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should be HttpGet:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }
```

Comment: thank you sir it worked, i have been stuck here and this was the issue lol. Thanks again